# Double Unity + Invincible follower and somehow I can still die

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

I have 2x unity (one on me and one on my follower with the token where he can't die) and somehow I am still able to die on PS4. Any idea why this is happening? Do I misunderstand how unity works or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: For what it's worth, when I take a killing blow, my follower dies too.

Comment: Unity doesn't keep your hp linked to your follower's.  It just splits incoming damage between all Unity users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding how Unity works. The damage is split, so you will still take the damage while he cannot die from any damage suffered.

For example, you both have 100 life, and you get hit for 200 damage. Both you and your follower would take 100 damage each. Your follower will not die because of the token, however you will still die because you have no item to keep yourself from dying (because there is no such item).

Comment: Actually there is, but it is destroyed upon reviving you. [Ancestors grave](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ancestors-grace)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Hardcore item only, and probably not applicable. But a nice item regardless. Also, anytime you die, your follower dies. This is to keep you from staying dead and your follower killing a boss because he can't die.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes more sense. In this case, does it matter what items your follower has for damage mitigation? If your follower has 1 hp vs 1000 hp, does that matter at all in how to best use unity?

Comment: That's correct, it doesn't matter what the follower's HP is at in this case. You are better getting items on them that boost their primary stat than anything else. Keep in mind their crit hit damage is capped at 150% so if you have gear that gets you to that cap, use a different gem in the weapon or vice versa.